# TS2322: Type is assignable to constraint of type V, but V could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint

Tags: typescript

I have the following typescript function

```
export const f1 = <V extends Record<string, any> & { name: string }>(vars: Omit<V, 'name'>, name: string): V => {
    const v: V = {...vars, name}
    return v
};
```

which gives the error

```
TS2322: Type  Omit<V, "name"> & { name: string; }  is not assignable to type  V 
 Omit<V, "name"> & { name: string; }  is assignable to the constraint of type  V ,
  but  V  could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint  Record<string, any> & { name: string; }
```

I do not see how that can be the case here.

Comment: It'll be unions. It's usually unions. :-) But I can't *prove* that because I'm only a journeyman in TypeScript, not a master. FWIW, though, here are two ways you can rewrite it to avoid the problem (I wasn't sure what result type you wanted): https://tsplay.dev/NDVpRW

Comment: Okay, unions *or* an explicit type argument. :-D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not that intuitive but I think easy way to look at it is that the function should also work if you are to specify the generic explicitly `f1<{}>(...)`.

So if you have type `T1` that fulfils `extends Record<string, any> & { name: string }`

```
type T1 = {
  name: number;
  other: "stuff";
} & {
  name: string;
};
```

This more less resolves as

```
{
    name: never;
    other: "stuff";
}
```

Then `Omit<T1, "name">` type is

```
{
    other: "stuff";
}
```

If you call `f1` like

```
f1<T1>({ other: "stuff" }, "name");
```

Then when you have `{ ...vars, name}` you get

```
{
    other: "stuff";
    name: string;
}
```

which does match specified generic

```
{
    name: never;
    other: "stuff";
}
```

Same example starting with a different type like

```
type T1 = {
  name: "some specific string";
  other: "stuff";
} & {
  name: string;
};
```

shows the same thing but maybe example is more realistic.

Comment: Ah, yes, that's the other way this happens. Simple example demonstrating how the return type can be wrong as a result: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKgpgHgDg9gTgFxMABAYxgOwM4JQMwEYUBeFAHgDUVIExMATbFAJTAzgfNzgEtMA5gBoUAQ0wBPAHwoAZCgDeKTKIC2YAFwoe-ASgC+UgBQA3UXGxaA8qt4IqIgOQr1jqSJebtCPoICUWtQkMgoAUCgR6Fi4KCaBpIoAdMlmFh5qYPrhkXBgCACucJixofoA3KGhGDh4udj5ADZ4ZETkCp5aAEQQnSKiWgAsAEyGRgr9KMP6Ip34MDCdfhXAqJEAegD8VdEwDWCJDTACRnWNCImeSygrKAAyR8yz852hN5HvH++bQA

Answer (score 0):

As [Max pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77444882/157247), it really is possible for the return type to be wrong if you provide the type argument explicitly. Here's an example using your `f1`:

```typescript
const result = f1<{name: "x", a: 42}>({a: 42}, "foo");
console.log(result.name); // Logs "foo"
//                 ^? −−−−−− but the type is `"x"`
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKgpgHgDg9gTgFxMABAYxgOwM4JQMwEYUBeFAHgDUVIExMATbFAJTAzgfNzgEtMA5gBoUAQ0wBPAHwoAZCgDeKTKIC2YAFwoe-ASgC+UgBQA3UXGxaA8qt4IqIgOQr1jqSJebtCPoICUWtQkMgoAUCgR6Fi4KCaBpIoAdMlmFh5qYPrhkXBgCACucJixofoA3KGhGDh4udj5ADZ4ZETkCp5aAEQQnSKiWgAsAEyGRgr9KMP6Ip34MDCdfhXAqJEAegD8VdEwDWCJDTACRnWNCImeSygrKAAyR8yz852hN5HvH++bQA)

You can solve it by keeping the type of `name` outside `V`. Here are two ways, depending on whether you want the result `name` to specifically be type `string` or to potentially be a narrower type (a string literal or union of them) depending on the input `vars`:

```
// First version, resulting type's `name` can be a union or string literal type, not just `string`
export const f1 = <V extends Record<Exclude<string, "name">, any>>(
    vars: V, name: string
): V & {name: string} => {
    const v = {...vars, name};
    return v;
};

const vars1 = {name: "x", a: 42} as const;
console.log(vars1.name);
//                ^?
console.log(vars1.a);
//                ^?
const result1 = f1(vars1, "y");
console.log(result1.name); // <== Note that this is not just `string`, but the literal type `"x"`
//                  ^?
console.log(result1.a);
//                  ^?

// Second version, `name` ends up as `string`
export const f2 = <V extends Record<Exclude<string, "name">, any>>(
    vars: V, name: string
): Omit<V, "name"> & {name: string} => {
// ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−− only change is here
    const v = {...vars, name};
    return v;
};

const vars2 = {name: "x", a: 42} as const;
console.log(vars2.name);
//                ^?
console.log(vars2.a);
//                ^?
const result2 = f2(vars2, "y");
console.log(result2.name);
//                  ^?
console.log(result2.a);
//                  ^?
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/PTAEDEEsCcGcBdQDcCmdIHsB2AaU0VYBXAG3kiwHNR4BPABxQHJZQADLAQwFsU3QAxpyygARilCdQRLJhEZooBNArUSkeGk4kaDFHiwZEAKyIJ2y1WwBQKAB70FiAdnMAzAIygAvKAA8AGqg9ppYACasAEooLtBhfgCidgIkRGEofpZUeABEXLw5AHx4wrSFhQAU1qA1yJxwAFygAQY8KE1ZlNYAlE1BAGSgAN757UrwKlQAvj6Fw9W1LljmSD7DAHSbSPWwrbxTANwLNQTwRNAiSEeH1tZLKzteviNtTTl2OSVNACwATDOcVj3eBHe4YEgodYkDCUCrbOAedajbpHEC1dEY9EAPQA-HdXODIdDYfDYIjOCjrGjMTSarj8ctEARiGQnqBPHDHrlaDlKWCIVCYRVmaR4IjkQdQGi-N5fAA5IwSeAAC04iBVkFYmtAhhMZkQbE6bDwoiI6uVEnUmmg2l0jHY7xyNmptNp9P5RKFItZ6wpqLArrdeKpYAAyjFsGFkGhYHI8Bw2vwUOFWER6JJWIaJlZbA4nIJXIg3L81oFgnZQhFQNFYvEkik0hlOrlRkUSlgypVjnVGs09mNOj0mgB5bgaQIttpFUCDF68DrZ6azeZorFr9cbzeAJCId7u9-uDzvQNgSLRBKqqBJtRaCN3gcg1kNNutSf2bujTudLtcjgyHnAS2eUY3g+L5QD+AEgULUECQFYlOQApE2kpF1A1qd1YM9Ekdl+X0UIDND0Lxe9vXgQD2V+BDYF+bleRg5ZCUFWFSNwiUQ0IzEMIYuCvUIUVcL9diOOxPEgA)